# In C#, how can I create a TextReader object from a string (without writing to disk)

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper, textreader

I'm using [A Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) to parse some pasted text into a webpage. The Fast CSV reader requires a TextReader object, and all I have is a string. What's the best way to convert a string into a TextReader object on the fly?

Thanks!

Update-
Sample code- In the original sample, a new StreamReader is looking for a file called "data.csv". I'm hoping to supply it via TextBox_StartData.Text.

Using this code below doesn't compile.

```
        TextReader sr = new StringReader(TextBox_StartData.Text);
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(sr), true))
        {
            DetailsView1.DataSource = csv;
            DetailsView1.DataBind();
        }
```

The `new StreamReader(sr)` tells me it has some invalid arguments. Any ideas?

As an alternate approach, I've tried this:

```
        TextReader sr = new StreamReader(TextBox_StartData.Text);
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(sr, true))
        {
            DetailsView1.DataSource = csv;
            DetailsView1.DataBind();
        }
```

but I get an `Illegal characters in path Error.` Here's a sample of the string from TextBox_StartData.Text:

```
Fname\tLname\tEmail\nClaude\tCuriel\tClaude.Curiel@email.com\nAntoinette\tCalixte\tAntoinette.Calixte@email.com\nCathey\tPeden\tCathey.Peden@email.com\n
```

Any ideas if this the right approach? Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 300, accepted):

Use [System.IO.StringReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.stringreader) :

```
using(TextReader sr = new StringReader(yourstring))
{
    DoSomethingWithATextReader(sr);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the `StringReader` class, which inherits `TextReader`.

Comment: `TextReader` is not an interface, it's an abstract class.

Answer (score 6):

`StringReader` *is* a `TextReader` (`StreamReader` is too, but for reading from streams). So taking your first example and just using it to construct the `CsvReader` rather than trying to construct a `StreamReader` from it first gives:

```
TextReader sr = new StringReader(TextBox_StartData.Text);
using(CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(sr, true))
{
  DetailsView1.DataSource = csv;
  DetailsView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon... I think there's a bug with the Fast CSV Framework. I'm getting a result that looks like this: !http://screencast.com/t/5wZRrjDMO...

Comment: My CSV is 
fname,lname,email
john,doe,jd@email.com

Comment: That (after I view-source to see that you are linking to http://screencast.com/t/5wZRrjDMO anyway) looks like you are producing a series of arrays of strings (one for each line), and trying to render them, which results in the text "System.String[]" repeated. This sounds to me like a reasonable result from a CSV parser, not handled well. Try outputting it to a grid-view and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Jon- Actually, I am using a GridView, I've tried a couple of them, but I'm guessing the data is being returned properly, it's just a matter of choosing the right Data Display Control..??

Comment: I tend not to make heavy use of controls, so there may be something there I'm missing. The output seems to be a series of arrays of strings (one array for each row, one string for each cell), which makes sense. Not sure why it's not working beyond that I'm afraid :(

Answer (score 5):

You want a [StringReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx)

```
var val = "test string";
var textReader = new StringReader(val);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the [StringReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx) class. It inherits from TextReader.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [the documentation for `TextReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx), you will see two inheriting classes. And one of them is [`StringReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx), which seems to do exactly what you want.