# CSVHelper how to map a string to object

Tags: c#, mapper, csvhelper

I have a string in a variable, rather than in a file.

Can I use the CSVHelper (https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) to parse the string and map it onto my object?

The code to map a CSV file works:

```
TextReader reader = new StreamReader("data.csv");
var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader);
var records = csvReader.GetRecords<CarModel>();
```

How can I change that to map a string to the object:

```
String carmodels "make,model,year\n\rFord,Escort,1998\n\rHonda,Civic,1994";
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(carmodels);
var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader);
var records = csvReader.GetRecords<CarModel>();
```

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C#, how can I create a TextReader object from a string (without writing to disk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837826/in-c-how-can-i-create-a-textreader-object-from-a-string-without-writing-to-di)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming the `CarModel` type is already mapped correctly, you can use a `StringReader` rather than a `StreamReader`:

```
string carmodels = "make,model,year\n\rFord,Escort,1998\n\rHonda,Civic,1994";
using (var reader = new StringReader(carmodels))
using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
{
    var records = csvReader.GetRecords<CarModel>();
}
```

Comment: `CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` for the new version.

Answer (score 0):

You "need" to setup a mapping for your class, so it know's which column goes to which property.
Even the `.AutoMap()` can work for you.
https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/auto-mapping/